# Case-insensitive regex to change html <br> tag

Tags: c#, regex

My requirement is to change all `<br />` tags to `<br>` in a string. `<Br />`, `<bR />`, `<BR />`, `<br />` all four combination in a string should be changed into `<br>`.

How to write a regex for this in C#?

Converting string into uppercase or lowercase is not allowed.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by your last sentence? Should `<bR />` become `<bR>` or `<br>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
result = Regex.Replace(subject, @"<br\s*/>", "<br>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: I don't believe this will preserve case on replacement.

Comment: @Oded: It shouldn't, at least that's how I read the question.

Comment: My reading of the last line is that the replacement should preserve case (not that difficult - just capture the `br` portion and replace with `\1`).

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
string _reg = Regex.Replace(keyword, "(?i)<br\\s*/>", "<br>");
```

Answer (score 0):

For case-insensitive `regex` try to use [***`IgnoreCase`***](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx) option (Specifies case-insensitive matching)