# HTML encode string in MVC Razor except for one tag

Tags: c#, html

I have a string which contains HTML in a Razor view.

```
var s = "A string.<br> It has <abbr>HTML</abbr>."
```

I want to HTML encode everything except for the `<br>`

```
s == "A string.<br> It has &lt;abbr&gt;HTML&lt;abbr&gt;."
```

This does not work:

```
@s.Replace("&lt;br&gt;", "<br>")
```

The strings come from a database of user created content and the only tags they *should* contain are `<br>`s, but in practice they might contain just about anything, and if they do I must keep it that way but display it in a safe way. Of course, the data should never have been saved this way to begin with, but it is, so I have to deal with it.

I can't just use `Html.Raw()` because I need to encode everything else. <strike>However, `Html.Encode()` encodes too much, converting `"\r"` to `"&#10;"` etc.</strike> (Something must have been funny with the data I tested this on the first time, `Html.Encode()` does not seem to be the issue any more).

Comment: I'd rethink what you're trying to do and approach the problem in a safer, more standard way.

Comment: I'm open to suggestions. What's the more standard way in the Razor world?

Comment: I don't have any information on where these strings are coming from, why they have html in them, or why you're trying to encode only some of the html, so I can't provide any meaningful suggestions. What I meant by safer is - can you avoid having to render strings with HTML? Can you separate (in storage and memory) the parts that should be encoded, and those that shouldn't? What happens if you have a proper `<br/>` instead of a `<br>` in your current string? String replace isn't safe there.

Comment: Also note that strings are immutable so `s.Replace("&lt;br&gt;", "<br>")` doesn't change `s`. You'd have to assign it like `s = s.Replace("&lt;br&gt;", "<br>")`

Comment: Put simply you can't. It's either encoded or it's not. You can't have some encoded and some not. @xdumaine, has the right idea. It appears your going about this the wrong way. Why not split your text into two strings, then but the <br> in the View? It's HTML, it belong's in the view.

Comment: @Liam I would have put it in the view if I controlled the data, but I don't :( But seriously, is there really no way of attaining the encoded string as a plain string and then doing whatever I like with it?

Comment: What your definition of a *plain string*? HTML encoded, URL encoded, UTF-8, UTF-16... A `<` character is HTML, so you need to HTML encode it if you want the browser to render these not as HTML. But you want to keep some of the `<` but not others. Only thing I can think would be to write a `Regex` to remove the `<br>` and replace them with something else, then encode it, then put them back. But you can't simply encode everything but.

Comment: [Here's a Regex for a br tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12579364/case-insensitive-regex-to-change-html-br-tag)

Comment: I think you're over-complicating the issue. I have input, I can't control how it's formatted. I have a goal I need to reach. I've stated both clearly. As you can see from my attempt with Replace() I tried to replace encoded `<br>`s with non-encoded `<br>`s, which does not work, probably because they aren't encoded until right before they are outputted.

Comment: The issue is not matching the tag, it's stopping it from being encoded.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48968/discussion-between-josef-ottosson-and-liam)

Comment: If I were you, I'd just write a short script converting all rows in the table: replace "<br>" with "\n". Your string split approach is technically the right way to do what you want: parse the original string character by character, if it forms the pattern "<br>" let it be, and html encode everything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
@Html.Raw(Html.Encode(str).Replace("&lt;br&gt;", "<br>"))
```

We encode the string using `Html.Encode` after which we convert the encoded tag `&lt;br&gt;` back to the `<br>` tag and use `@Html.Raw` to output it without being encoded again.

Comment: Unfortunately Html.Encode caused other issues, as explained in the question.

Comment: That's a much neater solution.

Comment: Tested this in a new, clean project, and it works there. So there must be something funny with the data I received when I tried Html.Encode() earlier.

Comment: Representing `<br>` with `[br]` is redundant, we're already representing it with `&lt;br&gt;`. I added the regex suggested by @Liam and got this: `@Html.Raw(Regex.Replace(Html.Encode(str), @"&lt;br\s*/*&gt;", "<br>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))`

Answer (score 2):

This looks a little ugly to me, but it works.

```
var splitString = s.Split(new string[] { "<br>" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
foreach (string line in splitString) 
{
    @line<br>
}
```